# Edit column heading in Unix

Tags: disk-usage

Is there any way to rename the heading that we get with the df -kh command. I tried a way to rename the heading and appending hostname to it as addition. But the code is a lot messy. Is there a cleaner way to [image]achieve this:-

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
df -h /dev/serv02ac | awk '{print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",$4, "\t",$5}' > newF
hostname > newF4
tail -n +2 newF >> newF4
tr '\n' '\t' < newF4 > newF2
echo 'Server Filesystem Total Capacity Amount Used %Full' > newF3
tail -n +1 newF2 >> newF3
echo '\n' >> newF3
cat newF3|mailx -s "Server Space Check" swagat@gmail.com
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to post your email address in a public place like this

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply pass the hostname as a variable into awk?

```
awk -v hostname="$(hostname)" 'NR==1 {print "System" "\t" $0; next} {print hostname "\t" $0}'
```

For example,

```
$ df -kh /dev/dm-0 | 
    awk -v hostname="$(hostname)" 'NR==1 {print "System" "\t" $0; next} {print hostname "\t" $0}'
System  Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
T61p    /dev/dm-0       162G  127G   27G  83% /
```

Comment: FWIW, may want to make the first "System" be space expanded to the length of the hostname 'cos otherwise a long hostname may cause tab expansion to not line things up.  Other than that this was almost exactly what I was about to post :-)  Or use `printf` formatting and `%-15s` type structures :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris hmm good points - in fact I'd considered not attempting to format prettily within awk, and simply piping the output through `column -t` (which is what I usually do - in practice)

Comment: @steeldriver/ Stephen Harris- Hey that works asum, But the only trouble is how do I modify the heading of the output. For mailing it, I need to change the heading like "Server Filesystem TotalCapacity  AmountUsed %Full" but what I get is the default one. Is there any way I can modify the heading also.

Comment: @Swagat you can modify the `NR==1` action (the part in braces) to print whatever you want in place of `$0`

Comment: @steeldriver I tried the same but the output is absurd when the filesystem is too lagre name. It breaks into a separate line and then I come up with absurd output like:-

Comment: @steeldriver With the filesystem it takes up the linebreak and starts the iteration again. It causes the defect.
System     Filesystem      Size       Avail     Capacity
T61p         /dev/dm2sfm217ncei
T61p  495M             359M    79% /